# Swift - Make a Slide to Unlock like button in iOS 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios6, uicontrol

i want to make a Button with an iOS 6 slide to unlock like gesture recognizer. How can I do this?

I already googled this but I only found articles for Objective-C

Comment: With a question this broad and vague, the appropriate answer is "by writing code." What part of it are you having trouble with? Nikita provided a good outline of what you'd need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this library - https://github.com/maail/MMSlidingButton.

If you don't like it, it would be easy enough to implement it yourself. Just create a container view, add an inner view (that will be sliding) and add UIPanGestureRecognizer to the container view. After that you could change the inner view position depending on the pan gesture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this works! But do you know how can I replace the Color to an Image I want that It look like the original Slider in iOS 6.

Comment: I don't think there is a build-in functionality for this, you will probably have to change the source code of that library. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.